# Copy characters from a file into an array in C programming

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have a file test.txt which have fields in the following way
abc,def

xyz,pqr

def,def

I want to read the file and store the value of abc,def like abde | xypq | dede and so on ,i.e only the first 2 alphabets.

The resulting values will be stored in array.
When i tried i did

```
FILE *myFile;
myFile = fopen("Integers.txt", "r");

//read file into array
char numberArray[16];
int i;

if (myFile == NULL)
{
    printf("Error Reading File\n");
    exit (0);
}
for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    fscanf(myFile, "%c,", &numberArray[i] );

}

for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
       printf("Number is: %c\n\n", numberArray[i]);
    }
```

It stores value 
`Number is : x
Number is : y
Number is : z`

and so on..

I want result to be like
`Number[0] is : abde
Number[1] is : xypq
Number[1] is : xypq`
 and so on

Comment: isn't it supposed to be %s rather than %c ?

Comment: It wont affect, still storing the value wrongly

Comment: right ... %s expects whitespace as separator ... put a if statement and check for comma. until then concatenate to same var

Comment: if  you could show me where shall i add it? I am not getting where to add and check for characters

Comment: Read your code and compare with what it should do according to your description. You will find several discrepancies. You are e.g. never reading two letters and the elements of `numberArray` cannot store two characters, and so on...